# Patch file in linux

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, compiling, patch

I have a patch file in following line:

```
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: ip.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: ivs.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: message.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: misc.o
diff -r ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc
64a65,68
> #ifdef        GgX
> #include "wireless-phy.h"
> #include "mac-802_11.h"
> #endif        GgX
128a133
> 
147a153,157
> 
> #ifdef  GgX
>       Mac802_11* macptr;
> #endif  GgX
> 
266a277,294
> 
> #ifdef GgX //GgX - To have an access to change rate!
>               } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "change_rate") == 0) {
>                       macptr = (Mac802_11*) ifhead_.lh_first->uptarget();
>                       if (macptr) {
>                               // Keep attention GgX supposes only 1
>                               // interface present!
>                               macptr->setRate(atoi(argv[2])); 
>                               fprintf(stderr, "Rate changed to: %d\n\n",\
>                                               atoi(argv[2]));
>                               return TCL_OK;
>                       } else {
>                               fprintf(stderr, "Error.. Mac not found..\n");
>                               return(TCL_ERROR);
>                       };
>                       return TCL_OK;
> #endif // GgX
>
```

How to patch this file to ns2.26?
I tried `patch -p0 < <file_patch>` but error:

```
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

Please help me.

Comment: That looks like the output of `diff -r` on two directories, but not intended to be used as input to `patch`. Try recreating it with `diff -u` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I just have a origin file and this diff file so how can i create patch file from diff output?

Comment: See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_create_a_patch . Can you clarify your question ? It appears you are running diff `diff -r ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc' you would just `diff -r ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc > patch.txt`. If this is in some file, everything after that diff command is the patch.